# AWS CodeBuild container outputs Access Denied with Terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

**Background:**

I'm working on a data pipeline that uses a collection of AWS resources (e.g. AWS glue, athena, s3, etc.). I'm using Terraform to deploy the AWS resources within AWS CodeBuild. All the Terraform configuration files are stored within a GitHub repo. The CodeBuild project uses the GitHub repo as its source.

**Problem:**

When the CodeBuild project is triggered, the `terraform apply` command is used to apply the .tf file configurations to the AWS resources. The  `terraform apply` command outputs the error:

[image: error output]

The CodeBuild project role has the following policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/codebuild/sparkify-CI",
                "arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:log-group:/aws/codebuild/sparkify-CI:*"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sparkify-dend-analytics"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:CreateReportGroup",
                "codebuild:CreateReport",
                "codebuild:UpdateReport",
                "codebuild:BatchPutTestCases",
                "codebuild:BatchPutCodeCoverages"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codebuild:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:report-group/sparkify-CI-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:vpc/vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ],
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:AcceptVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:AllocateAddress",
                "ec2:AssignIpv6Addresses",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:AssociateAddress",
                "ec2:AssociateDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:AssociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:AssociateSubnetCidrBlock",
                "ec2:AssociateVpcCidrBlock",
                "ec2:AttachClassicLinkVpc",
                "ec2:AttachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AttachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateCustomerGateway",
                "ec2:CreateDefaultSubnet",
                "ec2:CreateDefaultVpc",
                "ec2:CreateDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:CreateEgressOnlyInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateFlowLogs",
                "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateNatGateway",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:CreateRoute",
                "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateSubnet",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:CreateVpc",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpointConnectionNotification",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpointServiceConfiguration",
                "ec2:CreateVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnection",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:CreateVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteCustomerGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DeleteEgressOnlyInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteFlowLogs",
                "ec2:DeleteInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteNatGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:DeleteRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteRouteTable",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteSubnet",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DeleteVpc",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpointConnectionNotifications",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpointServiceConfigurations",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnection",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeClassicLinkInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeCustomerGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DescribeEgressOnlyInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeFlowLogs",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeMovingAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeNatGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfacePermissions",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribePrefixLists",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupReferences",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeStaleSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointConnectionNotifications",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServiceConfigurations",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServicePermissions",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServices",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeVpnConnections",
                "ec2:DescribeVpnGateways",
                "ec2:DetachClassicLinkVpc",
                "ec2:DetachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DetachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DisableVgwRoutePropagation",
                "ec2:DisableVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:DisableVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:DisassociateAddress",
                "ec2:DisassociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:DisassociateSubnetCidrBlock",
                "ec2:DisassociateVpcCidrBlock",
                "ec2:EnableVgwRoutePropagation",
                "ec2:EnableVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:EnableVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifySubnetAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointConnectionNotification",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointServiceConfiguration",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointServicePermissions",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcPeeringConnectionOptions",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcTenancy",
                "ec2:MoveAddressToVpc",
                "ec2:RejectVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:RejectVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:ReleaseAddress",
                "ec2:ReplaceNetworkAclAssociation",
                "ec2:ReplaceNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:ReplaceRoute",
                "ec2:ReplaceRouteTableAssociation",
                "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:RestoreAddressToClassic",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:UnassignIpv6Addresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**CodeBuild Project Configurations:**

Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:2.0

Environment type: Linux

Compute: 3 GB memory, 2 vCPUs

Privileged: False

Env Variables:

TERRAFORM_VERSION=0.12.28

**buildspec.yml:**

```
version: 0.2

phases:

  install:
    commands:
      - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/"$TERRAFORM_VERSION"/terraform_"$TERRAFORM_VERSION"_linux_amd64.zip
      - unzip terraform_"$TERRAFORM_VERSION"_linux_amd64.zip
      - rm terraform_"$TERRAFORM_VERSION"_linux_amd64.zip
      - mv terraform /usr/local/bin/
  build:
    commands:
      - echo $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER
      - BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF | cut -d'/' -f 3)
      - | 
        case $BRANCH_NAME in
          dev|prod) TF_COMMAND="apply -auto-approve";; \
          *) TF_COMMAND="plan";;
        esac
      - echo $BRANCH_NAME
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`curl --silent http://169.254.170.2:80$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI | jq -r '.AccessKeyId'`
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`curl --silent http://169.254.170.2:80$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI | jq -r '.SecretAccessKey'`
      - export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-west-2"
      - |
        for service in deployment/*/; do
          if [ -d "${service}/${BRANCH_NAME}/" ]; then
            #get list of non-hidden directories within ${service}/${BRANCH_NAME}/
            service_dir_list=$(find "${service}${BRANCH_NAME}" -type d | grep -v '/\.')
            for dir in $service_dir_list; do
              #if directory contains .tf or .tfvars files
              if (ls ${dir}/*.tf) > /dev/null 2>&1 || (ls ${dir}/*.tfvars) > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                cd $dir > /dev/null
                echo ""
                echo "*************** TERRAFORM INIT ******************"
                echo "******* At directory: ${dir} ********"
                echo "*************************************************"
                terraform init
                echo ""
                echo "*************** TERRAFORM $TF_COMMAND ******************"
                echo "******* At directory: ${dir} ********"
                echo "*************************************************"
                terraform $TF_COMMAND
                cd - > /dev/null 
              else
                :
                # echo "No Terraform file were found in ${dir}"
              fi
            done 
          else
            echo "No ${BRANCH_NAME} environment directory exists within ${dir}"

          fi

        done
```

**Attempts:**

1.

Use Codebuild container's access and secret key within AWS provider block.

How I get the container's credentials within the buildspec.yml:

```
- export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`curl --silent http://169.254.170.2:80$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI | jq -r '.AccessKeyId'`
- export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`curl --silent http://169.254.170.2:80$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI | jq -r '.SecretAccessKey'`
```

but then running `terraform apply` within CodeBuild results in the error:

```
error using credentials to get account ID: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: 
The security token included in the request is invalid. status code: 403, request id: x
```

2. 

Add `AmazonVPCFullAccess` to CodeBuild IAM role.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve. Passing `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` or secret key to the build_spec is a bad practice and shouldn't be used. Also what do you mean by "container's access and secret key"? Which container?

Comment: @Marcin I updated my post, let me know if you need more clarification. I was hoping I wouldn't have to use credentials within the buildspec.yml too, given the info within the Terraform AWS provider docs (see under section "CodeBuild, ECS, and EKS Roles"): https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#codebuild-ecs-and-eks-roles:~:text=This%20support%20is%20based%20on%20the,services%20or%20manually%20for%20advanced%20usage.

Comment: They say terraform should automatically pick up the credentials from the container role. This does not work?

Comment: Can you update your question with full permission denied error. And from which machine you are running terraform apply? In cloud or from local?

Comment: @Marcin The CodeBuild project's role is not picking up the credentials.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I added a screenshot of the initial CodeBuild error.  I'm running terraform apply within the Cloud.